# How to place plugin on _getSelect in Price filter category

Tags: magento2.2, layered-navigation

I am working with module need customization with category layernavigation
I found class `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter\Price` has been used in several places. I think it must be very important.  When I look I see more details:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
 */
private $layer;
```

I wonder why `$layer` property is private? If anyone can short explain what layer is that would be great.

Second I found the function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve clean select with joined price index table
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select
 */
protected function _getSelect()
{
 //Alot codes here
}
```

Is there a way to place plugin on above function, I want to add my code to filter follow my custom attributes and join query to another table ? It is a right place or i visit wrong place.

I don't want use `preference` in this case if no anymore choice. Override core function maybe very risky in future

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add plugins for protected methods. Maybe you can find a public method that uses the `_getSelect` method and write a plugin for that.